# How to avoid div wrap on float element and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e04wfxj6/

Sidebar needs to stay at 100px as it is.
Content seems to wrap around sidebar and the first .row takes the height of sidebar.
I'm trying to get rid of wrapping.

```css
#sidebar {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#sidebar ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
#content {
  background: beige;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#content .row {
  background: brown;
}
#content .row > div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sidebar and Content should be side by side, not on top of each other. In your fiddle they look on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/e04wfxj6/1/)

change the `.container-fluid` element wrapper position. Because you use bootstrap to build the gird layout. So, the `.container-fluid` should wrap all of the page elements.

Comment: This is just one section of the interface, it's contained within many more elements, so the overall container is not the issue.

Comment: @there still has problem on your layout.http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Please pay more attention **.row** and **.container** restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `#content`.
https://jsfiddle.net/kd4z0vyy/

Comment: Try duplicating a row once more... it doesn't work anymore if Content is taller than Sidebar.